# Expectation of `fractional' Geometric brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let stochastic processes $S^a=(S^a_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and $S^b=(S^b_t)_{t\geq 0}$ solve the following two SDEs
$$dS^a_t=S^a_tdB^a_t$$ and $$dS^b_t=S^b_tdB^b_t$$
respectively, with $S_0^a>0$ and $S_0^b>0$ and Brownian motions $B^a$ and $B^b$ are independent. Let $W^a_t=\frac{S^a_t}{S^a_t+S^b_t}$. Then how do we obtain explicit expression for $\mathbb{E}[W^a_t]$?

My attempt: Since they are both geometric Brownian motions, so we have $S^k_t=S_0^ke^{-\frac{1}{2}t+B^k_t}$ and $\mathbb{E}[S^k_t]=S_0^k$ for $k\in\{a,b\}$. By Ito lemma, we have
$$dW^a_t=W^a_t(1-W^a_t)(1-2W^a_t)dt+W^a_t(1-W^a_t)dB^a_t-W^a_t(1-W^a_t)dB^b_t.$$
It follows by taking the expectation on both sides and we have
$$\mathbb{E}[W^a_t]=W_0^a+\int_0^t\mathbb{E}\bigg[W^a_s(1-W^a_s)(1-2W^a_s)\bigg]ds.$$

Then I don't know how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can actually compute $\mathbb{E}[W_t^a]$ without needing to go through Ito's formula.  First, note that since $S_t^a \stackrel{(d)}{=} S_t^b$ we have

$$1-W_t^a = 1-\frac{S_t^a}{S_t^a+S_t^b} = \frac{S_t^b}{S_t^a+S_t^b} \stackrel{(d)}{=} W_t^a.$$

Now we can compute

$$ 1 = \mathbb{E}[W_t^a + (1-W_t^a)] = \mathbb{E}[W_t^a] + \mathbb{E}[(1-W_t^a)] = 2 \mathbb{E}[W_t^a]$$

so $\mathbb{E}[W_t^a] = \frac 12$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But $S_0^a$ and $S_0^b$ can differ, so unless $S_0^a=S_0^b$ we won't have $S_t^a$ equals $S_t^b$ in distribution.